# SVN MERGE: Non-ancestrally Branch to Trunk

Tags: svn, svn-merge

I want to merge a branch which is just committed to the branch folder (was not actually branched) to the trunk. Here is the detail.

```
repo/
    /trunk
         /mymagento     // at rivision 500

    /branch
        /magento
        /magento1.6
        /magento1.7     //at rivision 480
```

Magento1.7 was not actually branched from trunk mymagento. 
The Idea is to megre changes of Magento1.7 into mymagento so that it gets upgraded.

I have tried these svn Merge forms so far:

```
merge sourceURL1[@N] sourceURL2[@M] [WCPATH]

merge sourceWCPATH1@N sourceWCPATH2@M [WCPATH]

Where WCPATH = /var/www/magento/
```

I tried a lots of param like `--accept theirs-full`  `--reintegrate`  `--ignore-ancestry` (of course with proper syntax)

But none of them is working properly. At max I get the svn property change marked to Merged. But not the actual changes of files from Magento1.7

After the merged command on taking diff, SVN reports following information

```
Property changes on: dropdown.js
 ___________________________________________________________________
 Modified: svn:mergeinfo
 Merged /branches/magento1.7/js/lib/dropdown.js:r5154
```

Please suggest me what I should do in this case? 
Many Thanks for your time & effort.